# Handle an extremely large list for the Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my python code, I have the following line

```
vals = [True] * n
```

This code works when `n` is a small number but I want this to work when `n ~ 100,000,000` without getting a `MemoryError`

I even tried using a dictionary like this but it still wont work

```
vals = {}
for i in range(0, n):
    vals[i] = True
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit**
For those of you wondering what I am trying to do. I am trying to implement the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm to generate prime numbers. The `vals` variable keeps track of the composite numbers which are found later on in the algorithm

**Edit 2**
I don't think so I can use generators because I need to able to change values later on like this:

```
vals = [True] * n
for i in range(0, n):
    if condition:
        vals[i] = False
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If you use your large lists as arrays, you may want to use ``numpy``, which handles arrays more efficiently.

Comment: You can generate primes by not keeping things in memory (using generators or something), but I don't think it's accurate to call it a sieve if you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `numpy` you can handle your large list:

```
import numpy as np

vals = np.ones(100000000,bool)
print(vals)
# [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
```

Comment: numpy is good because it's well explored.  However, I don't think it works fully with pypy yet, nor jython nor ironpython.  CPython !+ Python.  You may find that a pure python solution on pypy would outperform the C extension module route.

Answer (score 1):

Do not keep all the data in memory, only keep what is needed at the moment or keep some other representation so generate it on the fly.

In this case, you should probably use a "thin air" representation instead:

- keep the list of all the primes found so far and
- for each prime, keep the composite number that this prime's filter was last triggered on
- Then, walk the number axes a single time and check for each prime-last_multiple pair if the current number is the next multiple

Alternatively, you can offload your data to disk and e.g. use offsets to access elements (that would be rather slow) or write a class with a list-like interface that would use disk and a cache, loading and offloading data when needed (`mmap` is a good backing choice IMO).

Comment: I’m not sure we can say “in this case” without seeing any more code.

Comment: This is my best guess with what is available right now.

Comment: Thanks, Ill definitely try your suggestion. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use generators

```
vals = lambda n: (True for _ in range(n))
```

EDIT: since OP asked for a numpy implementation

```
n = 100000000
prime = lambda n: list(filter(lambda x: (x % np.arange(2, 1+int(math.sqrt(x)))).all(), range(2, n+1)))
```

Comment: You should prefer `xrange` since with Python 2.x, `range` actually tries to allocate an array (instead of returning a generator).

Comment: @user3426575 `range` in python 3 (which OP is using) is the same as `xrange` in python 2

Comment: I could use that but it wont work in my case because I need to be able to change a True to a False at different indices. See edit

Comment: @krimson then I'd use numpy and filter. I wouldn't recommend prepopulating a bare array this large. Would that solution be ok?

Comment: numpy sounds well suited for this problem, if you could show me an example of how you can populate an array of 100M elements and change them later on based on a given index, then it would definitely work. Sorry I'm not to experienced with python

Comment: @Krimson you can use `numpy.zeros(100000000, dtype=bool)`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a generator:

```
def vals():
    for i in range(0, n):
        yield True
```

For compatibility with Python 2.x, it might be preferable to use `xrange`:

```
try:
    xrange
except NameError:
    xrange = range

def vals():
    for i in xrange(0, n):
        yield True
```

Otherwise, your program will silently run out of resources if run with an older interpreter.

Comment: in python3 (which OP has tagged) `xrange` will raise a `NameError`.

Comment: I think `xrange` is not avaliable in python 3, as OP is using it (see tag).

Comment: I cant use generators. Sorry for not being so specific earlier. See edit 2

Answer (score -2):

Check these out:

http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/bits_mod/

http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/sieve/

The first is a bit array type that uses at least 31 bits of multiple ints.

The second is a sieve built on that bit array type.

If you *still* need something that won't fit into memory, you might look into modifying bits_mod to use mmap, as done in, for example: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/drs-bloom-filter/

Here's some timing information, using pypy3 2.4.0, in case you decide to go the numpy route, but remain curious how pypy3 could do:

```
$ time ./sieve 100000000 > /dev/null
Creating bit array
Clearing multiples of 2
Clearing multiples of 3
Clearing multiples of 5
Clearing multiples of 7
...
Clearing multiples of 9931
Clearing multiples of 9941
Clearing multiples of 9949
Clearing multiples of 9967
Clearing multiples of 9973

real    1m10.749s
user    1m8.133s
sys     0m2.405s
```